# How to properly close window right after it finishes loading in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, window

This question is not about the `jQuery.fn.ready()`.

I open a new window with `window.open()` for file download, and wants to close the window after the download is started. Most browsers will continue the file download so I don't need to wait until the download is finished.

The problem is when I close the window with `jQuery.fn.ready()`, the file download is skipped straight away.

Here is what I tried and failed:

```
var w = window.open(...);

$(w).load(); // failed
$(w.document).load(); // failed
$(w.document).contents().load(); // failed
$(w.document).contents().find('body').load(); // failed
```

**EDIT:**

Adding jsFiddle for easy demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vicary/Yjkt8/1

**EDIT 2:**

By Jonny Sooter's answer, updated jsFiddle with a working version http://jsfiddle.net/vicary/Yjkt8/4.

Comment: You can try to work with a time out? Say 700ms. That should be time enough for everything to have loaded.

Comment: `w.onload = function() { w.close(); }`

Comment: @BramVanroy that's a bad idea. You have to take slow internet connections into account.

Comment: @adeneo Gave that a try but no luck, added jsFiddle in the question for that.

Comment: Check out the accepted answer in [this][1] question: 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545311/download-a-file-by-jquery-ajax

Answer (score 1):

You can try this if you know the downloading time.

```
jQuery(window).load(function () {
    alert('page is loaded');

    setTimeout(function () {
        alert('page is loaded and 1 minute has passed');   
    }, 60000);

});
```

Comment: The timeout is arguable when network latency is always unpredictable.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {
        var w = window.open(),
            d = w.document,
            s = d.createElement("script");

        s.type = "text/javascript";
        s.innerHTML = ";(function(){window.close();})();";

        d.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);
    });
});
```

**Update:**

For chrome you can try:

```
window.open('', '_self', ''); //bug fix
window.close();
```

Or try:

```
window.self.close();
```

Comment: Seems, legit. Corrected your script to make it work properly.

Comment: Still not working, Chrome seems preventing code injection to `window.close()` alone. Loading a page that calls this function works.